# What is the easier way to make a MySQL dump from the server covered by the jump server under ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh

Currently to get the MySQL dump I have to do it step by step:

1. ssh to jump server
2. ssh from jump server to dedicaded server
3. Make a dump using "mysqldump"
4. Compress the dump using tar.
5. Copy it to the jump server using "scp"
6. Copy it to local comp using "scp"
7. Clean up

Is there an easier way to get the dump?
Additional constrains: jump server doesn't have neither mysql nor any compressors and I don't have permissions to install them. The dump should be compressed because actual dump's size is 300-450 Mb and the spead is 125 Kb/s.

Comment: `ssh -J user1@jump user2@dedicaded 'mysqldump ... | gzip -c' > sql.gz` ?

Comment: @jhnc It says: "'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". Can I use "tar" in that example somehow?

Comment: how do you invoke `tar` currently?

Comment: @jhnc tar -czf dump.tar.gz dump.sql